How should I have diagnosed this? Figuring out when to insert code into hooks to alter third party package behaviour
This question seems very confused to me, so I'm not sure you will be able to make sense of it.
I know how to solve this problem (now). What I would like to know is how I should have diagnosed and solved it. Solving it took me roughly 24 hours (admittedly, this issue was not my sole occupation). That seems an excessively long time given that I isolated the problem relatively easily and the solution was relatively well-documented. What took the time was figuring out where --- or, perhaps more accurately, when to put it.
My actual code is rather more complicated but, the greater complexity didn't really make it harder to find the problem.
The basic issue is a need to generate one or more glossaries but prevent glossaries from creating titles, toc entries and page breaks at the top level. But I do want glossaries to create titles for sub-glossaries, where two or more sets of glossary entries are grouped under a single main heading.
I quickly found: Print glossaries without title and Print glossaries without title. [Remarkably quickly given I used SE's search.]
So I spent the next 23 hours trying to figure out where/when to intervene.
In retrospect, what complicated things was that I was trying to intervene from a class rather than in the document itself. It seems which hook to use is a delicate matter, even though you can make the changes before or after \begin{document} if you do it in the document directly.
A change made up to begindocument seems to work; one made in begindocument/after doesn't. A change made right before \printglossary in the class does work, but only locally. Trying to change the section command from the class seems to fail after begindocument except very, very close to \printglossary. Yet cmd/printglossary/before doesn't work either.
So very few places work, intervention-wise. How should I have found these particular places? In particular, how could I have established that I needed to make the change either earlier or only much later rather than, as I expected, a bit later?
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname-g1.tex}
\ProvidesFile{\jobname-g1.tex}
\newglossaryentry{a}{name=a,description=A,type=ga}
\newglossaryentry{b}{name=b,description=B,type=gb}
\newglossaryentry{c}{name=c,description=C,type=gc}
\newglossaryentry{m}{name=m,description=M}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% the next line doesn't work
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument / after } { . / my glossaries }
% the next line does work (begindocument/before works, too)
% \hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { . / glossaries }
% the following line also works
% \hook_gput_code:nnn { package/glossaries/after } { . }
{
  \setglossarysection {subsection}
  \renewcommand* \glsclearpage {}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand \mything {+m}
{%
  \cleardoublepage
  {\parindent=0pt
    \hrule\par
    {\Huge #1\par}%
    \hrule\par   
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mywords {ommo}
{% intervening up here somewhere doesn't work
  \mything{#3}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}%
    \IfValueTF{#4}{%
      % intervening here works, but { cmd/printglossary/before } doesn't
      \printglossary[title={#2},type=#2]%
      \printglossary[title={#4},type=#4]%
    }{%
      \printglossary[title={},type=#2]%
    }
}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,subentrycounter,toc,xindy]{glossaries}
\newglossary[ga-glg]{ga}{ga-gls}{ga-glo}{As} 
\newglossary[gb-glg]{gb}{gb-gls}{gb-glo}{Bs} 
\newglossary[gc-glg]{gc}{gc-gls}{gc-glo}{Cs} 
\setglossarystyle{altlist}
\loadglsentries{\jobname-g1}
\makeglossaries
% Uncommenting the following line works
% \setglossarysection{subsection}
\begin{document}
% uncommenting this line works
% \setglossarysection{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\mything{T}
\gls{a} \gls{b}  \gls{c} \gls{m}

\mywords[b]{ga}{A-B-Words}[gb]

\mywords{gc}{C-Words}

\mywords{main}{M-Words}

\end{document}

I can, for example, view the content of the begindocument hooks:
-> The hook 'begindocument/after':
> The hook is not declared.
> Code chunks:
>     top-level/myglossaries -> \setglossarysection {subsection}\renewcommand *
\glsclearpage {}
> Document-level (top-level) code:
>     ---
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     ---
> Execution order:
>     Not set because the hook is undeclared.
<recently read> }

l.895 \hook_show:n { begindocument/after }

?

-> The hook 'begindocument':
> Code chunks:
>     amsmath -> \reset@strutbox@ \MakeRobust \dddot \MakeRobust \ddddot \mathc
hardef \std@minus \mathcode `\-\relax \mathchardef \std@equal \mathcode `\=\rel
ax \expandafter \let \csname overleftarrow \endcsname \@undefined \expandafter
\let \csname overrightarrow \endcsname \@undefined \MakeRobust \overrightarrow
\MakeRobust \overleftarrow \MakeRobust \overleftrightarrow \MakeRobust \underri
ghtarrow \MakeRobust \underleftarrow \MakeRobust \underleftrightarrow
>     datatool-base -> \@ifundefined {texteuro}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {\texte
uro }}\@ifundefined {textdollar}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {\textdollar }}\@ifund
efined {textstirling}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {\textstirling }}\@ifundefined {t
extyen}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {\textyen }}\@ifundefined {textwon}{}{\DTLnewcu
rrencysymbol {\textwon }}\@ifundefined {textcurrency}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {
\textcurrency }}\@ifundefined {euro}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {\euro }}\@ifundef
ined {yen}{}{\DTLnewcurrencysymbol {\yen }}
>     glossaries -> \ifglsacronym \providecommand *{\printacronyms }[1][]{\prin
tglossary [type=\acronymtype ,##1]}\fi \ifx \gls@codepage \@empty \@ifpackagelo
aded {fontspec}{\def \gls@codepage {utf8}}{}\fi \gls@begindocdefs \@ifpackagelo
aded {amsmath}{\let \gls@if@measuring \@gls@if@measuring }{}\let \gls@org@refst
epcounter \refstepcounter \let \gls@org@label \label \renewcommand *{\@gls@adju
stmode }{\ifvmode \mbox {}\fi }
> Document-level (top-level) code (executed last):
>     ---
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     ---
> Rules:
>     ---
> Execution order:
>     amsmath, datatool-base, glossaries.
<recently read> }

l.896 \hook_show:n { begindocument }
?

-> The hook 'begindocument/before':
> The hook is empty.
<recently read> }

l.897 \hook_show:n { begindocument/before }

?

But this seems to confirm that my code in begindocument/after is running after any default setup is done. That suggests it should be equivalent to using the code in the document after \begin{document}, but the latter works, whereas the former fails.
So what is different about code running in the begindocument/after hook and code run after \begin{document}, when the hook contains no other code which might interfere? Why does the code need to go in an earlier hook, even though the timing is immaterial if inserted into the document itself?

There is no begindocument/after hook, you meant begindocument/end. The message said that the hook is not declared.

@UlrikeFischer I should just crawl away and die ....

not you should certainly not @cfr ... please

@FrankMittelbach Thank you.
